# updateProfile() in Firebase +Vue.js

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have some function like :

```
var s = new Vue({
  el: "#sPage",
  data: {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    confirmPassword: '',
    displayName: ''
  },
  methods: {
    createAccount: function() {

      if (this.password.length < 6) {
        alert('Password must contain more than 6 characters')
        return
      }
      if (this.password != this.confirmPassword) {
        alert('Confirm password not match')
        return
      }

      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).then(() => {
        user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        console.log(this.displayName)
        user.updateProfile({
           displayName: this.displayName
        });
          }).catch(function(error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
              alert('The password is too weak')
            } else {
              alert(errorMessage)
            }
            console.log(error)
          })
          alert('Register success')
          this.email = ''
          this.password = ''
          this.confirmPassword = ''
          this.displayName = ''
        }
    }
```

In this line:

```
  user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        console.log(this.displayName)
        user.updateProfile({
          displayName: this.displayName
        });
```

when i use console.log(this.displayName) the value of this.displayName it show blank value
[image]

My form :

```
<input v-model="displayName" type="text" placeholder="Display Name" />
```

How can I get the real value that binding with displayName
Thank you

Comment: It is difficult, with the code you show in your question to know why `this.displayName` is null in the `createAccount method. A simple and "stupid" question: Do you manually enter a value in the field before calling the method?

Comment: Another comment: Since `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` returns a promise containing a `firebase.auth.UserCredential`, as detailed in the doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword, you should be able to get the user with `userCredential.user`

Comment: i can add it when i use getElementById('buttonID') to get displayName value that i insert to form @RenaudTarnec . now my problem is how can i get this.displayName value that binding to form

Comment: Your code seems correct from the Form Input bindings point of view. If you get correct values for `this.email` and `this.password` you should also get a value for `this.displayName` if these three fields are filled in.

Comment: Is arrow function can use outside variable ? @RenaudTarnec

Comment: Can you please be more precise? What do you mean?